# Error: (SystemJS) [BABEL] unknown: Unknown option: direct.0

Tags: npm, babeljs, versioning, systemjs, jspm

I'm rather new to **jspm** and all this **SystemJS** and transpiling thing.

I have created this **Express.js** - **Angular** app and it runs without problems on my Linux Mint.

On my friend's Mac, though - as well as on my old Windows computer - this pops up in the browser console:

```
Error: (SystemJS) [BABEL] unknown: Unknown option: direct.0
    ReferenceError: [BABEL] unknown: Unknown option: direct.0
        at Logger.error (http://localhost:3000/jspm_packages/npm/babel-core@5.8.24/browser.js:11516:11)
        at OptionManager.mergeOptions (http://localhost:3000/jspm_packages/npm/babel-core@5.8.24/browser.js:12024:29)
        at OptionManager.init (http://localhost:3000/jspm_packages/npm/babel-core@5.8.24/browser.js:12114:10)
        at File.initOptions (http://localhost:3000/jspm_packages/npm/babel-core@5.8.24/browser.js:10754:75)
        at new File (http://localhost:3000/jspm_packages/npm/babel-core@5.8.24/browser.js:10744:22)
        at Pipeline.transform (http://localhost:3000/jspm_packages/npm/babel-core@5.8.24/browser.js:16076:16)
    Error loading http://localhost:3000/src/boot/boot.js
        at Logger.error (http://localhost:3000/jspm_packages/npm/babel-core@5.8.24/browser.js:11516:11)
        at OptionManager.mergeOptions (http://localhost:3000/jspm_packages/npm/babel-core@5.8.24/browser.js:12024:29)
        at OptionManager.init (http://localhost:3000/jspm_packages/npm/babel-core@5.8.24/browser.js:12114:10)
        at File.initOptions (http://localhost:3000/jspm_packages/npm/babel-core@5.8.24/browser.js:10754:75)
        at new File (http://localhost:3000/jspm_packages/npm/babel-core@5.8.24/browser.js:10744:22)
        at Pipeline.transform (http://localhost:3000/jspm_packages/npm/babel-core@5.8.24/browser.js:16076:16)
    Error loading http://localhost:3000/src/boot/boot.js
```

Any idea what is going on there?

I have been fiddling around with versions of `babel` in `config.js`/**jspm** and `package.json`/**npm**, and who knows, I might have been close to a solution at some point, but I don't really know what [I'm doing](http://media2.giphy.com/media/MS0fQBmGGMaRy/giphy.gif) and why.

These are the (hopefully) relevant parts from
**package.json**:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "jspm install",
    "serve": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    // ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    // ...
    "jspm": "^0.16.48"
  },
  "jspm": {
    "directories": {
      "baseURL": "app",
      "lib": "app/src"
    },
    "dependencies": {
      // ...
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "-a": "npm:babel-core@5.8.24",
      "-a-runtime": "npm:babel-runtime@5.8.24",
      "core-js": "npm:core-js@1.1.4",
      "traceur": "github:jmcriffey/bower-traceur@0.0.92",
      "traceur-runtime": "github:jmcriffey/bower-traceur-runtime@0.0.92"
    }
  }
}
```

...and **config.js**:

```
System.config({
  defaultJSExtensions: true,
  transpiler: "-a",
  paths: {
    "app/*": "src/*.js",
    "github:*": "jspm_packages/github/*",
    "npm:*": "jspm_packages/npm/*"
  },

  map: {
    "-a": "npm:babel-core@5.8.24",
    "-a-runtime": "npm:babel-runtime@5.8.24",
    // ...
    "core-js": "npm:core-js@1.2.7",
    "css": "github:systemjs/plugin-css@0.1.32",
    "json": "github:systemjs/plugin-json@0.1.2",
    "text": "github:systemjs/plugin-text@0.0.4",
    "traceur": "github:jmcriffey/bower-traceur@0.0.92",
    "traceur-runtime": "github:jmcriffey/bower-traceur-runtime@0.0.92",
    "npm:babel-runtime@5.8.24": {
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2"
    },
    "npm:core-js@1.2.7": {
      "fs": "github:jspm/nodelibs-fs@0.1.2",
      "path": "github:jspm/nodelibs-path@0.1.0",
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2",
      "systemjs-json": "github:systemjs/plugin-json@0.1.2"
    }
  }
});
```

Please halp

Comment: Did you come up with a solution?